# parallel reads from Athena (AWS) database, via R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, jdbc, parallel-processing, amazon-athena

I've got a largish dataset on an Athena database on AWS. I'd like to read from it in parallel, and I'm accustomed to the `foreach` package's approach to forking from within R.

I'm using `RJDBC`

Here's what I am trying:

```
out <- foreach(i = 1:length(fipsvec), .combine = rbind, .errorhandling = "remove") %dopar% { 
    coni <- dbConnect(driver, "jdbc:awsathena://<<location>>/",
           s3_staging_dir="my_directory",
           user="...",
           password="...")
    print(paste0("starting ", i))
    sqlstring <- paste0("SELECT ", 
           "My_query_body" 
           fipsvec[i]
    )
    row <- fetch(dbSendQuery(coni, sqlstring), -1, block = 999)         
    print(i)
    dbDisconnect(coni)
    rm(coni)
    gc()
    return(row)
}
```

(Sorry I can't make this reproducible -- I obviously can't hand out the keys to the DB online.)

When I run this, the first `c = number of cores` steps run fine, but then it hangs and does nothing -- indefinitely as far as I can tell.  `htop` shows no activity on any of the cores.  And when I change the for loop to only loop over `c` entries, the output is what I expect.  When I change from parallel to serial (`%do%` instead of `%dopar%`), it also works fine.

Does this have something to do with the connection not being closed properly, or somehow being defined redundantly?  I've placed the connection within the parallel loop, so each core should have its own connection in its own environment.  But I don't know enough about databases to tell whether this is sufficiently distinct.

I'd appreciate answers that help me understand what's going on under the hood here -- it's all voodoo to me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the `RJDBC` package (and it's dependencies-- `methods`, `DBI`, and `rJava`) into the cluster anywhere?

If not, your the first line of your code should look something like below:

```
results <- foreach(i = 1:length(fipsvec),
                   .combine = rbind,
                   .errorhandling = "remove",
                   .packages=c('methods','DBI','rJava','RJDBC')) %dopar% {
```

One thing that I suspect (but don't know) might make things a little hairier is that RJDBC uses a JVM to execute the queries. Not super knowledgeable about how rJava handles JVM initialization, and if each of the threads may be trying to re-use the same JVM simultaneously, or if they have enough information about the external environment to properly initialize one in the first place.

Another troubleshooting step if the above doesn't work might be to move the assignment step for `driver` into the `%dopar%` environment.

On another track, how many rows are in your result set? If the result set is in the million+ row range and can be returned with a single query, I actually came across an opportunity for optimization within the `RJDBC` package and have an open pull request on github ( https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/pull/50 ) that I haven't heard anything on but have been using myself for a couple months. There's a basic benchmark documented in the pull request, I found the speedup to be substantial on the particular query I was running.

If it seems applicable you can install the branch with:

```
library(devtools)    
devtools::install_github("msummersgill/RJDBC",ref = "harmonize", force = TRUE)
```

Comment: It isn't the `.packages` argument.  In my experience this is only important in windows machines.  And anyway the parallel script works fine when I loop over 4 entries on a 4-core instance.  So each thread can perform one -- and only one -- iteration.  Trying moving the driver inside now...

Comment: One other step to try might be including the line `.jinit(force.init = TRUE)` as the first line in the %dopar% environment as well. (but I'm really just spit-balling at this point, don't have a rock solid understanding of the java side myself either)

Comment: Moving the driver call inside doesn't help either.  Will try the `harmonize` branch now -- the reason I'm trying to do this in parallel is that I get errors when trying to read large chunks into memory.  I only have about 1e5 rows, but I have 3000 columns, and I need most of them.

Comment: Is the error related to java heap size being exceeded? And if so, have you tried increasing the memory allocation for the JVM? If not, you can allocate more memory with `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")` where the characters "8g" correspond to a 8 gigabytes of memory.

Comment: yeah tried increasing memory; no help.  and the `.jinit` thing did no good either.  working on the `harmonize` thing now, but that will allow me to avoid parallelism, rather than enabling parallelism

Comment: ...and the `harmonize` branch didn't prevent the error that has been keeping me from downloading ~3000x3000 chunks of the dataset at a time.  The performance improvement in downloading a 40x3000 chunk was marginal, and may have just been noise.

Comment: Just noticed that you're querying against Amazon Athena which brought this issue to mind https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/issues/31 . Based on your nested `fetch(dbSendQuery...` call I'm getting a sneaking suspicion this may be old news to you, is part of the issue related to the Athena block size limitation?

Comment: Also FWIW, it may be worth posting the error messages you're getting on the large chunk query attempt. I suspect the overhead associated with parallelization in this case is substantial, seems like avoiding altogether would probably result in best performance.

Comment: Whoops, link should have been for issue #44, not 31: https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/issues/44

Comment: Yeah, I found that thread in previous debugging.  And I've figured out that this problem doesn't happen when I go through Amazon's GUI.  I'm thinking that I should probably figure out how to do this in some other language (java?  IDK any java...) and then call that as a `system` call from within R